# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.graph_stores'

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index, nebula-graph

I am trying to use the `NebulaGraphStore` class from `llama_index` via `from llama_index.graph_stores.nebula import NebulaGraphStore` as suggested by the [llama_index documentation](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/index_structs/knowledge_graph/NebulaGraphKGIndexDemo.html), but the following error occurred:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 from llama_index.graph_stores.nebula import NebulaGraphStore

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.graph_stores'
```

I tried updating `llama_index` (version 0.10.5) with `pip install -U llama-index` but it doesn't work. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of llama-index do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using version 0.10.5

Comment: Do you have a local python script of your own that is named `llama_index.py`?

Comment: No I don't think so. I have tried this on both my device and a virtual machine. Both returned the same error. I can import other things from `llama_index.core` and `llama_index.llm` just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to latest doc of llama-index, all graph-store module are not included in llama-index core packages and needs to install it by pip:

```
%pip install llama-index-llms-openai
%pip install llama-index-embeddings-openai
%pip install llama-index-graph-stores-nebula
%pip install llama-index-llms-azure-openai
```

https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/index_structs/knowledge_graph/NebulaGraphKGIndexDemo.html